# Changing the foreground and background colors of substrings based on ANSI escape codes

Tags: java, strings, console

I am checking for particular keywords in a string, and then changing the foreground and background colors of substrings based on the keywords. Following is the snippet for checking the background code:

```
if(string.contains("[30;42m") || string.contains("[31;42m") || string.contains("[32;42m") ||
    string.contains("[33;42m") || string.contains("[34;42m") || string.contains("[35;42m")
    || string.contains("[36;42m") || string.contains("[37;42m")){
        //the parameter of indexOf and replaceAll will be one from the above
        //using [30;42m as an example
        index = string.indexOf("[30;42m"); 
        string = string.replaceAll("\\[30;42m", "");
        backgroundColor = Color.GREEN;
        //foreground is already set using separate conditions for 30,32,32...37m
     }
```

Is there any way that I can do something as I have shown above? Currently, I have separate conditions for each substring, which doesn't incorporates "DRY" principle. My code is working, but I am looking for a way to reduce these `if` statements.

**Edit:**
The if blocks are for setting the background and foreground colors. For example if I have "34;42" code, this means text foreground color is Blue and background color is Green, and so on.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more conetext on the implementation inside the if-block? I strongly suspect the refactoring strategy will change, depending on how you impelemented the body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it a little more generic but I'm afraid you still have to test each.

I don't know if your case is always changing to green or not.
If not I suggest the following enum :

```
/**
 *
 * @author chillworld
 */
public enum ColorMapperEnum {
    GREEN("[30;42m",Color.GREEN) ,
    RED("[31;42m",Color.RED) ,
    BLACK("[32;42m", Color.BLACK) ,
    BLUE("[33;42m", Color.BLUE); // and so on

    private String textToFind;
    private Color targetColor;

    private ColorMapperEnum(String textToFind, Color targetColor) {
        this.textToFind = textToFind;
        this.targetColor = targetColor;
    }

    public String getTextToFind() {
        return textToFind;
    }

    public Color getTargetColor() {
        return targetColor;
    }
}
```

Now you can do a whole lot more generic in your java code :

```
for (ColorMapperEnum colorMapper : ColorMapperEnum.values()) {
    if(string.contains(colorMapper.getTextToFind()){
        index = string.indexOf(colorMapper.getTextToFind()); 
        string = string.replaceAll("\\" + colorMapper.getTextToFind(), "");
        backgroundColor = colorMapper.getTextToFind();
    }
 }
```

I did use the same naming as yo but I **advice** to take better naming.
String string => very bad, for what stands it?

Now I don't know if there could be a case that multiple conditions are true and what there must be done when multiple conditions are true.

An enum `values()` has always the same result **in the same** order.
Use that in your advantage when tackling that problem.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, yes you are right. I just need to set three values instead of two: textToFind, foregroundColor, BackgroundColor

Comment: One more thing, willn't it be better from performance viewpoint if I use a hash table?

Comment: where exactly? in stead of the enum?

Comment: Yes,instead of using enum.

Comment: Actually Enum is better. You have to construct once. Always singleton and accesible in each class.  If you need foreground also change `targetColor` to `backgroundColor` and add a color for `foregroundColor`. Add the second color in the constructor and values of the enum. (if help needed ask and I refactor code here). Is it possible that 30 and 31 are in the same string?

Comment: Its perfectly okay. I made the changes and it worked perfectly :) Thank you so much !

Comment: glad that we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

One idea I'd have here is maybe use a different approach and parser your string into Tokens.

Have a Token each for the color markers (a simple 2-tuple/pair implementation will do) and the non-marker strings in between.

So a string such as

```
This[30;42m is an[31;42m Example
```

would become a list like (pseudocode)

```
String("This"), Tuple(30, 42), String(" is an"), Tuple(31, 42), String(" Example")
```

Now you just need to iterate over the list, compare each tuple with the set of tuples you are looking for, building a new list that you can finally turn back into a string.

I hope this is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to support 8 background colors, and probably 8 foreground colors as well.  That would be 64 magic strings that you are looking for, with 64 cases to handle them all.  With so many cases, string matching is inappropriate; you want to do pattern matching.  Pattern matching should be done using regular expressions.

Furthermore, you're probably better off writing a proper ANSI terminal emulator, or at least just a state machine to [support for changing colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).  The following class breaks up an input string into multiple colored strings.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class ANSIAttrString implements Iterable<ANSIAttrString> {

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static class TermState {
        public static final TermState DEFAULT = new TermState(Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK);

        public final Color fg, bg;

        public TermState(Color fg, Color bg) {
            this.fg = fg;
            this.bg = bg;
        }

        public TermState(TermState init, String[] attrs) {
            Color fg = init.fg;
            Color bg = init.bg;
            for (String attr : attrs) {
                switch (attr) {
                  case  "0": fg = DEFAULT.fg;
                             bg = DEFAULT.bg;
                             break;

                  case "30": fg = Color.BLACK;          break;
                  case "31": fg = Color.RED;            break;
                  case "32": fg = Color.GREEN;          break;
                  case "33": fg = Color.YELLOW;         break;
                  case "34": fg = Color.BLUE;           break;
                  case "35": fg = Color.MAGENTA;        break;
                  case "36": fg = Color.CYAN;           break;
                  case "37": fg = Color.WHITE;          break;
                  case "39": fg = DEFAULT.fg;           break;

                  case "40": bg = Color.BLACK;          break;
                  case "41": bg = Color.RED;            break;
                  case "42": bg = Color.GREEN;          break;
                  case "43": bg = Color.YELLOW;         break;
                  case "44": bg = Color.BLUE;           break;
                  case "45": bg = Color.MAGENTA;        break;
                  case "46": bg = Color.CYAN;           break;
                  case "47": bg = Color.WHITE;          break;
                  case "49": bg = DEFAULT.bg;           break;
                }
            }
            this.fg = fg;
            this.bg = bg;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return fg + " on " + bg;
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private static class Iter implements Iterator<ANSIAttrString> {
        private final String s;
        private Matcher m;
        private TermState state;
        private int index;

        Iter(String s, TermState init, Matcher m) {
            this.s = s;
            this.state = init;
            this.m = m;
        }

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return this.m != null;
        }

        public ANSIAttrString next() {
            if (this.m == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }

            int thisEnd = m.find() ? m.start() : m.regionEnd();
            try {
                return new ANSIAttrString(s.substring(index, thisEnd), this.state);
            } finally {
                if (m.hitEnd()) {
                    this.m = null;
                } else {
                    String[] attrs = m.group(1).split(";");
                    state = new TermState(state, attrs);
                    this.index = m.end();
                }
            }
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public final TermState state;
    public final String string;

    private static final Pattern SGR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "\\e\\[(\\d+(?:;\\d+)*)m"
    );

    public ANSIAttrString(String string) {
        this(string, TermState.DEFAULT);
    }

    public ANSIAttrString(String string, TermState state) {
        this.state = state;
        this.string = string;
    }

    public Iterator<ANSIAttrString> iterator() {
        return new Iter(this.string, this.state, SGR_PATTERN.matcher(this.string));
    }

}
```

Test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "It's a \u001b[31mRainbow\u001b[34;43m colored\u001b[39m world.";
    for (ANSIAttrString ats : new ANSIAttrString(str)) {
        System.out.println(ats.state + ": " + ats.string);
    }
}
```

> ```
> java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255] on java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]: It's a 
> java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0] on java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]: Rainbow
> java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255] on java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=0]:  colored
> java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255] on java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=0]:  world.
> ```